# Globally Shared Redux Container

Tags: reactjs, redux

**Summary**

I want to have a global messenger that has a reference to `store`. Let's call it a `Messenger`. I need to use it across different containers. It doesn't have its counterpart React component.

**What I have right now**

```
class Messenger {
  constructor(store, webview) {
    if (!chrome.runtime.id) {
      return false;
    }

    this.webview = webview;
    this.store = store;

    if (chrome.runtime.id) {
      chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(this.messageHandler);
      chrome.commands.onCommand.addListener(this.commandHandler);
    }
  }

  sendMessage(msg) {
    if (this.webview.contentWindow) {
      this.webview.contentWindow.postMessage(msg, "*");  
    }
  }
}
```

Messenger should be initialized with a `store` and `webview` objects like below:

```
$(function() {
  // exposing sandboxMessenger to a global namespace
  // so it can communicate with webview and sandbox
  window.app = {};
  app.sandboxMessenger = new SandboxMessenger(store, $('webview')[0]);

  ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
      <App />
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('app')
  );
});
```

But the above setting requires me to have the `webview` object completely outside of React environment like below:

```
<div id="app"></div> <!-- This part will be populated by React -->

<div id="webview-container">
  <!-- This part is isolated because I need to find it via $('#webview')[0];
  and pass it to Messenger -->
  <webview id="webview" src="sandbox/sandbox.html" partition="static"></webview>
</div>
```

**What seems ideal to me**

I want to contain `webview-container` DOM into a separate `Webview` React Component. When it is mounted, I will initialize `Messenger` because I have a `webview` object.

**Problem**

I don't have `store` object if I tried to follow the above case. If I passed down `store` explicitly, then I'd have to subscribe manually to store in all of my child containers.

**Question**

What's the best way to deal with this specific situation, and what's a general way to implement a *global Redux container*?

Comment: Like a higher order component?

Comment: The Provider IS a global redux container. Why not have it at the highest level and work inside it? What's a use case where that wouldn't work?

Comment: @ZekeDroid From a `Messenger` object, how do I get the reference to the global redux container? I can't think of any other way than exposing `store` object to `window.store = store`.

Comment: Ah alright, but why not put the `Messenger` inside the `Provider`?